# Sampling Frequency For Samples That Are Greater Than 1 Second

Tags: sampling

I understand that sampling @ X times per second is X Hertz. What if the sampling rate is given in minutes? 5 minutes for example.

5*60=300

Is that 1/300 Hertz or 0.003333~ Hertz?

Comment: Yes. If something happens every 300 seconds, its frequency is 1/300 Hz.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that 1/300 Hertz or 0.003333~ Hertz?

Yes.  Or 3.33mHz, if you prefer.  The appropriate sampling rate is all in how fast the plant responds to input -- I'm not sure what is actually used, but if you're controlling the water level behind a dam then 3mHz is probably fast.